Cannot use SDL Ada Bindings on Ubuntu 22.04
Building sdlada is ok, via alr, is ok, but the running step fails ($ alr run).
sdlada_2.5.20_cd53c280$ alr run
ⓘ Running pre-build actions for sdlada=2.5.20...                            
make : on entre dans le répertoire « /media/dubois/4To/Donnees/Courrier/020-Ada/X-Bibliotheque/sdlada_2.5.20_cd53c280/build/gnat »
mkdir -p gen/src/
make : on quitte le répertoire « /media/dubois/4To/Donnees/Courrier/020-Ada/X-Bibliotheque/sdlada_2.5.20_cd53c280/build/gnat »
ⓘ Building sdlada=2.5.20/build/gnat/sdlada.gpr...
✓ Build finished successfully in 0.47 seconds.
error: Executable "sdlada" not found
dubois@db:/media/dubois/4To/Donnees/Courrier/020-Ada/X-Bibliotheque/sdlada_2.5.20_cd53c280
$ 

-And second issue, the "with sdlada" fails on :
$ ./gnatmake -P unit_tests.gpr
--------------------------------
Compilation du unit_tests
--------------------------------
Compile
   [Ada]          unit_tests.adb
unit_tests.adb:28:06: error: file "aunit.ads" not found
unit_tests.adb:29:06: error: file "aunit.ads" not found
unit_tests.adb:30:06: error: file "aunit.ads" not found
unit_tests.adb:30:06: error: "Unit_Tests (body)" depends on "Sdl_Suites (spec)"
unit_tests.adb:30:06: error: "Sdl_Suites (spec)" depends on "Aunit (spec)"
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
$ 

with unit_tests.adb as:

with AUnit.Run;
with AUnit.Reporter.Text;
with SDL_Suites;

procedure Unit_Tests is
 etc..

Thanks
Mark

alr run will fail, because sdlada is a library crate, not a binary one (i.e. no executable is built).
As to the second problem, the following isn’t guaranteed (for macOS-related reasons; you should be good on Ubuntu), and there might be simpler solutions ...
cd unit_tests
alr init --in-place --bin unit_tests
alr with aunit
alr with sdlada --use=..

That will create alire.toml. Now edit it, and insert the line
project-files = ["../build/gnat/unit_tests.gpr"]

before the line [[depends-on]].
alr run should now build the unit_test executable and run it.

You might consider raising an issue on the Github project.
